# Django: Select count of foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

I have the following models:

```py
class SystemTable(models.Model):
    id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    system_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    system_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    system_url = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(StatusLkp, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='status',default=1)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'system_table'
        managed = True
        db_table = 'system_table'


class SystemPagesTable(models.Model):
    id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    system = models.ForeignKey(SystemTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    page_link_xpath = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    flag = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(StatusLkp, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='status',default=1)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'system_pages_table'
        managed = True
        db_table = 'system_pages_table'
```

I want to perform the following SQL query:

```sql
select
  s.*,
  (select count(*) from page p where p.system_id = s.id) as NUM_OF_PAGES
from system s;
```

How do I perform the above query with Django's ORM *without having to use a `for` loop*?
I do not want a result based on one system, I want to retrieve **all systems** with their page counts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
System.objects.annotate(num_pages=Count('page'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have indeed tried that, but the following error is returned:  

`Cannot resolve keyword 'page' into field. Choices are: date_created, id, status, status_id, system_desc, system_name, system_url`

Comment: @Maher do you use `related_name` or `related_query_name` as foreign key argument? If yes you should use name from `related_name` instead of `page`. See details here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name

Comment: I do not use `related_name` in my model. I tried including it and using the name in the `Count()` method but it also returned the same error sadly.

Comment: @Maher that's strange, can you show the full code of your models?

Comment: I have updated the question body with detailed models as they look in my project.

Comment: @Maher your model is named `SystemPagesTable` so try to use it's lowercased name inside Count method: `SystemTable.objects.annotate(num_pages=Count('systempagestable'))`

Comment: That is what I tried after your first comment, I got it from the documentation as well (lowercased name of class). It still doesn't work for some reason. Have been trying to find out why for a week now :\

Comment: @Maher interesting, what happens if you try following query `SystemTable.objects.first().systempagestable_set.all()`? Does djnago see `systempagestable_set` relation?

Comment: it works. The relation is there and it retrieves the 4 pages I have in the first system.